# How to import a tikZ figure which has images as dependencies?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, include, includegraphics, import

I came up with a tikZ figure, which I have written in a file, lets call it `A.tex`. This figure uses image files (.jpg, ...), which are included as nodes using `\includegraphics`.
Now obvisously, I'd like to `\import` the figure `A.tex` in my main document file `main.tex`, but it seems like LaTeX can't find the individually loaded `jpg`s. My filesystem structure is as:

```
document_root_dir
     |
     -----main.tex
     -----figures
             |
             ---A.tex
             ---neededImage1.jpg
             ---neededImage2.jpg
```

Instead of `\import`I also tried `\include` which does not throw an error, but also does not load/display the figure.
Therefore I am wondering, what  am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

### main.tex

```
\documentclass[./report.tex]{subfile}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
        \import{figures/A.tex}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

### A.tex

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning, backgrounds,scopes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (img1) at (0.5,0.5) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{neededFile.jpg}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that allows compilation of `main.tex` and also of `A.tex` separately:

- Call the `\import` command with two arguments (path and filename): `\import{./figures/}{A.tex}`
- Load the packages `standalone`, `tikz` and `import` in the main file.

Here is a working example. Note that I use `article` instead of `subfile` and that the image filename `neededFile.png` might be different in your case.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \begin{center}
        \import{./figures/}{A.tex}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**A.tex**

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning, backgrounds,scopes,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (img1) at (0.5,0.5) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{neededFile.png}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works nicely, but now obviously the figure alone can't be compiled. Isn't it also possible somehow to do this? Thats why I had the `standalone`at the figure.

Comment: @avermaet See updated answer using the `import` package, which now allows compilation of the figure alone. I guess the only thing that you were missing was `\import{./figures/}{A.tex}`